# How to merge Point Cloud Cluster of different size

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, point-cloud-library, matlab-cvst

I am working with 3D point cloud using PCL. I am using Fast Point Feature histogram (FPFH) as a descriptors which is 33 Dimensional for a single point. In my work I want to do clustering of point cloud data using FPFH where clusters are defined this feature.

However, I am confused as if I compute the FPFH of a cluster containing say 200 points than my feature vector of each point in a cluster is 200 x 33. Since two clusters will have different size I cannot use the feature vector of size like above. My question is how can I appropriately compute the features and use it to describe the cluster using single 1 x 33 dimension vector?

I was thinking of using mean but than it mean does not capture relative information of all distinct point.

Answer (score 0):

The FPFH descriptor is calculated **around** a point (from the points neighbouring that point - using either a k nearest neighbour or a fixed radius selection typically), not **from** the point. So no matter what the size of the cluster, the FPFH calculated from it will only be 33 dimensional. So for each cluster you just need to feed all the points in the cluster to the FPFH calculation routine and get the 33 dimensional feature vector out. You may also need to specify a point cloud containing the points around which to calculate the feature vector. If you do this per cluster, just send the centroid of the cluster (a single point) - and make sure the radius/k is big enough so that all points in the cluster are selected.